# How can I filter a list in Flutter based on the words it contains?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used .where on the List to filter like this:-

`List<AppUsageInfo> get eyes => (_appInfo.where((element)=>element.packageName=='apple')).toList();`

This works but I want to filter with more than just one word. When I try the following code:

`List<AppUsageInfo> get eyes => (_appInfo.where((element)=>element.packageName=='apple'||'google')).toList();`

I get the error **'The operands of the operator '||' must be assignable to 'bool.'**

I tried using brackets around 'apple and 'google' to see if it changes anything but that didn't seem to work.
Any help would me much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `||` accepts only booleans for both of the operands of the operator.

```dart
_appInfo.where((element) => element.packageName == 'apple' || element.packageName == 'google').toList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```dart
List<AppUsageInfo> get eyes => 
_appInfo.where((element)=>['apple', 'google'].contains(element.packageName)).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks it works!
The bracket before _appInfo is not closed, removing that solves the issue.

Comment: @Pranav Bahl, thanks for notice. I just copied and pastes from your question. Fixed.